# Что такое множество классов вычетов по модулю n?

Tags: математика

Что такое сравнимы 2 числа по модулю я знаю, это когда a ≡ b (mod n)
если n делит (a - b)

Что такое множество классов вычетов по модулю n?

с источников я понял что обозначаеться как Zn, где n - это и есть модуль.

пример Zn = {[0], [1],  [2]},  каждый єлемент называеться классом эквивалентности?

И что такое класс вычетов?
это когда в каждом классе єквивалентности  есть множество в котором каждые 2 пары элементов сравнимы  по модулю?
пример:
[0] = [....-6,-3,0, 3,6.....]   тут модулю n = 3.

И что в теме сравнимости значит этот символ "⊕"???. это операция с классами эквивалентности?

Comment: На сколько понимаю, класс вычетов по модулю n - множество всех целых чисел, сравнимых между собой по модулю n. Все подобные классы и составляю множество классов вычетов по модулю n. Их будет, собственно, ровно n.

Answer (score 2):

Множество классов вычетов по модулю `m` - это множество чисел `0`,`1`,...,`m-1`. Обозначается [image: Z/mZ]

На множестве `Z/mZ` определены операции сложения, вычитания, умножения и деления. Я обозначу их `[+]`, `[-]`, `[*]` и `[/]`, чтобы отличать от обчных операций сложения и умножения целых чисел:

- `a [+] b = (a+b)%m` - остаток от деления обычной суммы `a` и `b` на `m`,
- `a [*] b = (a*b)%m` - остаток от деления обычного произведения `a` и `b` на `m`,
- `[-]a = m - a`, и `[-]0 = 0`. Соответственно `a [-] b = a [+] ([-]b)`

Деление - самая хитрая операция в множестве вычетов. `a [/] b` - это такое число `c`, что `b [*] c = a`. Так вот, в отличие от целых чисел, которые делятся друг на друга довольно редко, классы вычетов делятся друг на друга почти всегда. Для этого необходимо и достаточно, чтобы `a` и `b` не имели общих делителей с `m`. Если `m` - простое число, то все ненулевые пары `a` и `b` можно делить. Для деления `Z/mZ` используется [расширенный алгоритм Евклида](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0#%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83).

Как это связано с классами эквивалентности. Возьмем ваш пример `Z3 = {[0],[1],[2]}`

Класс эквивалентности `[0]` обозначает все те целые числа, которые при делении на 3 дадут остаток 0: `[0] == {0, ±3, ±6, ±9, ...}`

Класс эквивалентности `[1]` обозначает все те целые числа, которые при делении на 3 дадут остаток 1: `[1] == {1, -2, 4, -5, 7, -8, 10 ...}`

Класс эквивалентности `[2]` обозначает все те целые числа, которые при делении на 3 дадут остаток 2: `[2] == {2, -1, 5, -4, 8, -7, 11 ...}`

Операции с классами эквивалентности определяются так (для определённости рассмотрим сумму): давайте возьмём из каждого класса по одному представителю, сложим их и в качестве результата возьмём класс эквивалентности получившейся суммы. Например `[1] [+] [2]` - возьмём из `[1]` число 1, а из `[2]` возьёмем 2. `1+2 = 3`. Класс эквивалентности, к которому принадлежит 3 - это `[0]`. Следовательно, `[1] [+] [2] = [0]`

Несложно доказать, что эти операции сводятся к операциям по модулю, как я написал выше, за исключением деления. Поэтому в реальной жизни никто не морочит себе голову классами эквивалетности, а просто рассматривают числа по модулю.